# Why does my subnet and VPC show side by side on CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc, subnet

I've been trying to figure out why my VPC and subnet show side by side instead of the subnet inside of the VPC? (I used Atom to generate this.)

```yaml
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "vpc",
    "Metadata": {

    },
    "Parameters": {"siggyVpcCidr": {
        "Description": "vpc cidr",
        "Type": "String",
        "Default": "10.0.0.0/16"
    },
    "siggySubnetCidr": {
        "Description": "cidr for the subnet",
        "Type": "String",
        "Default": "10.0.1.0/2"
    },
    "Subnet1Az": {
        "Description": "AZ for siggySubnetCidr",
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::AvailabilityZone::Name"
    }
  },
    "Mappings": {

    },
    "Conditions": {

    },
    "Resources": {
      "siggyVpc": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": { "Ref": "siggyVpcCidr" },
        "Tags": [{ "Key": "Name", "Value":  "siggyVpc" }]
      }
    },
    "siggyIgw": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::InternetGateway",
      "Properties": {
        "Tags": [{ "Key": "Name", "Value":  "siggyIgw1" }]
      }
    },
    "AttachGateway": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment",
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": { "Ref": "siggyVpc" },
        "InternetGatewayId": { "Ref": "siggyIgw" }
      }
    },
    "SubnetSiggy": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "Properties": {
        "AvailabilityZone": { "Ref": "Subnet1Az" },
        "VpcId": { "Ref": "siggyVpc" },
        "CidrBlock": { "Ref": "siggySubnetCidr" },
        "Tags": [{ "Key": "Name", "Value":  "siggySubnetCidr" }]
      }
    }
    },
    "Outputs": {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

They are separate resources. CloudFormation templates arrange resources in a flat array. This is pretty much true of most resources. Some resources can be implicitly defined when creating resources, but that probably won't be reflected with an export where you create a template from existing resources.

You would need to inspect the `VpcId` property to determine the VPC to which the subnet belongs.